# How to swipe between layouts in the viewflipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a several buttons in the first layout in the viewflipper, and I would like to know how I can swipe over the buttons and switch to the second layout that is also in the viewflipper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To swipe between layouts in a ViewFlipper use the following methods

[showPrevious()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showPrevious%28%29)

[showNext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#showNext%28%29)

or

[startFlipping()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#startFlipping%28%29)

the first two methods are derived from the parent class [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)

For an example please refer to the following link:

http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/view-flipper-example-android.html

Of course in your case, you should trigger the showPrevious/showNext/startFlipping in the onClick method for your button